# Função recursiva para visão computacional em Python

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens, visão-computacional

Estou desenvolvendo um método para encontrar contornos e objetos pretos em uma imagem. Tenho a chamada de uma função recursiva a partir de um determinado pixel, e na teoria a função deveria ser chamada até que o contorno todo estivesse completo. Isso não está acontecendo, ela está terminando a execução antes do previsto. Segue:

```
def cresce_regiao(pixel, num_regiao, imagem):
    if pixel not in tabela_comparacoes:
        tabela_comparacoes.append(pixel)
        if imagem.getpixel(pixel)[0] == 0:
            tabela_regioes.append((num_regiao, pixel))
            cresce_regiao(pixel, num_regiao, imagem)
    if (pixel[0], pixel[1] + 1) not in tabela_comparacoes:
        pixel = (pixel[0], pixel[1] + 1)
        tabela_comparacoes.append(pixel)
        if imagem.getpixel(pixel)[0] == 0:
            tabela_regioes.append((num_regiao, pixel))
            cresce_regiao(pixel, num_regiao, imagem)
    if (pixel[0] - 1, pixel[1]) not in tabela_comparacoes:
        pixel = (pixel[0] - 1, pixel[1])
        tabela_comparacoes.append(pixel)
        if imagem.getpixel(pixel)[0] == 0:
            tabela_regioes.append((num_regiao, pixel))
            cresce_regiao(pixel, num_regiao, imagem)
    if (pixel[0], pixel[1] - 1) not in tabela_comparacoes:
        pixel = (pixel[0], pixel[1] - 1)
        tabela_comparacoes.append(pixel)
        if imagem.getpixel(pixel)[0] == 0:
            tabela_regioes.append((num_regiao, pixel))
            cresce_regiao(pixel, num_regiao, imagem)
    if (pixel[0] + 1, pixel[1]) not in tabela_comparacoes:
        pixel = (pixel[0] + 1, pixel[1])
        tabela_comparacoes.append(pixel)
        if imagem.getpixel(pixel)[0] == 0:
            tabela_regioes.append((num_regiao, pixel))
            cresce_regiao(pixel, num_regiao, imagem)
```

A ideia é que a função compare o pixel com seus quatro vizinhos (horizontal e vertical) e, se forem pretos, adicione aos pixels pertencentes àquela região. Acontece que a função está executando a partir de um dos contornos que tenho em uma imagem, e ela acaba não detectando ele por completo. Queria entender se tem alguma coisa errada na minha recursão ou algo do tipo, pq já to olhando tanto tempo pra isso que to vendo tudo duplo...

Segue imagem de exemplo, destacando os pixels que a função detecta quando coloco ela pra ler o contorno exterior da imagem:

[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Reparem que ao invés de seguir até o fim do contorno, fazendo toda a volta, parece que ela chega em algum beco sem saída e não consegue voltar.

Comment: Tenta usar uma mascara em de um unico pixel, acredito que pode haver falhas na continuidade da linha do desenho

Comment: A chamada recursiva a grow_region é feita depois de o pixel em cada bloco condicional ter sido atualizado. Não poderá isto significar que cada chamada recursiva começa com um novo ponto (atualizado) e não com o ponto original?